# Verificar se um caminho é relativo ou absoluto

Tags: java, sistema-de-arquivos

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função do Java que verifica se a string é um caminho relativo ou não:

Ex:

```java
String caminho = funcao("\\pasta\\arquivo.xml")  // retorna true que é um caminho relativo
String caminho2 = funcao("c:\\pasta\\arquivo.xml") // retorna false não é caminho relativo
```

Ou também se já existe alguma função que eu passando a string ele me retorna o caminho completo:

Ex:

```java
String caminho3 = funcao("\\pasta\\arquivo.xml"); // retorno: c:\pasta\arquivo.xml
String caminho4 = funcao("c:\\pasta\\arquivo.xml");  // retorno: c:\pasta\arquivo.xml
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Verificar caminho relativo

O método [`File.isAbsolute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isAbsolute%28%29) diz se o caminho é absoluto. Então basta negar (`!`) o retorno para saber se ele é relativo.

Veja um exemplo:

```java
File f1 = new File("..");
System.out.println("\"" + f1.getPath() + "\" -> " + f1.isAbsolute());

File f2 = new File("c:\\temp");
System.out.println("\"" + f2.getPath() + "\" -> " + f2.isAbsolute());
```

Isso vai imprimir:

> ".." -> false
>
> "c:\temp" -> true

## Recuperando o caminho absoluto

Para retornar o caminho completo use o método [`getAbsolutePath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath%28%29) de uma instância da classe `File`.

Veja mais um exemplo:

```java
File arquivo1 = new File("\\pasta\\arquivo.xml");
System.out.println("\"" + arquivo1.getPath() + "\" -> " + arquivo1.getAbsolutePath());

File arquivo2 = new File("c:\\pasta\\arquivo.xml");
System.out.println("\"" + arquivo2.getPath() + "\" -> " + arquivo2.getAbsolutePath());
```

Isso vai imprimir:

> "\pasta\arquivo.xml" -> C:\pasta\arquivo.xml
>
> "c:\pasta\arquivo.xml" -> c:\pasta\arquivo.xml

---

**Nota**: em Java não se costuma usar o termo *função*, geralmente chamamos de métodos já que eles são sempre membros de classes.

Comment: Descordo de sua nota final. Parece dizer que uma função só pode ser chamada de função se a linguagem tiver funções de primeira classe.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo O que eu quis dizer foi que em Java não se chama um método de função. Uma função, no meu entendimento, consiste num procedimento qualquer que fica no escopo global, em algum *namespace* ou *lib*, mas o Java não tem isso. Mas realmente uma linguagem pode ter funções ou procedimentos sem que eles sejam de primeira classe.

Comment: Eu na verdade não conheço Java na prática... mas sempre achei que qualquer coisa que retorne um resultado seria chamado de função. Os que não retornam de método, e ambos seriam procedimentos.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Veja esta pergunta no SOEN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/what-is-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Comment: Acabei fazendo uma pergunta aqui no SOPT... mas tem um material bem interessante nessa resposta do SOEN. Foi mal poluir tanto essa resposta... devia ter feito a pergunta antes. Você acha que eu devia apagar os comentários?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Acho que não precisa apagar, não tem outros comentários mesmo.